# Should the size of the photos be the same for deep learning?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I have lots of image (about 40 GB).
My images are small but they don't have same size.
My images aren't from natural things because I made them from a signal so all pixels are important and I can't crop or delete any pixel.

Is it possible to use deep learning for this kind of images with different shapes?

All pixels are important, please take this into consideration. 
I want a model which does not depend on a fixed size input image. Is it possible?

Comment: thanks for you edit BCJuan

Comment: Lukasz Tracewski it's not my answer

Comment: I stand corrected then. Have you thought of using fully convolutional network? It can work with arbitrary input size.

Comment: actually my samples have different input size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing what you're trying to learn from the data, it's tough to give a definitive answer:

- You could pad all the data at the beginning (or end) of the signal so
  they're all the same size. This allows you to keep all the important
  pixels, but adds irrelevant information to the image that the network
  will most likely ignore.
- I've also had good luck with activations where you take a pretrained
  network and pull features from the image at a certain part of the
  network regardless of size (as long as it's larger than the network
  input size). Then run through a classifier.
  https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/activations.html#d117e95083
- Or you could window your data, and only process smaller chunks at one
  time.
  https://www.mathworks.com/help/audio/examples/cocktail-party-source-separation-using-deep-learning-networks.html